# helper.form action to route controller doesn't pick play.http.context or prefix using compile time DI injection in play 2.7 or 2.6

Tags: playframework

play.http.context suppose to add the context in url path for all routes and assets

I have tried have play.http.context= "/test" and also added prefix to have "/tests" while creating route in compile-time DI using BuiltInComponentsFromContext

In application.conf

> play.http.context = /tests

login.scala.html looks like

> @helper.form(action = routes.LoginController.authenticate)

Route looks like

> POST /login controllers.LoginController.authenticate

html generated

> form action=”/login" method=“POST"

I am expecting action to be action="/tests/login" as my play.http.context is “/tests” and also have added prefix to have “/tests” white creating route using BuiltInComponentsFromContext

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in application.conf file. I have used this in my project with play 2.7

```
play.http.context = "/test"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using withPrefix rather that passing prefix as parameter while creating routes object.

> new Route(......).withPrefix("/test")